# Check Duplicated records in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table storing user's information, including SSN. Now I need to write a query to prevent, or to check, when there is person who start to insert some new record into the table, if the new records' SSN is the same with someone who currently in the system, then it return false, or reject the insert.

I know how to count same SSN in a table, but this is sort of before insert check, should I do this on the front end level?

Update: So I think through this again, I am asking about, how can I actually allow the insert, and also every time we do the insert, there will be a check, if the new insert have duplicate SSN with one of our current client, then there will be a new column called "DuplicatedSSN"=True. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The only proper way to do this is by creating a `UNIQUE` constraint on the SSN field. Once that is in place, attempts to `INSERT` duplicates will fail, which your application can check for.

Comment: Alternatively, you can maintain a list of current SSNs and if the new SSN is not in the list, accept the value else reject it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks, but what if I haven't created this UNIQUE constraint, and I want to sort of capture this person, because for some reason this is some benefit related application, people who enter their SSN twice, may be seen as a fraud, so we need to write their name down. Which means, we will write their record into the application, but not fully. But I think your answer is great. I did not summarize my question well enough.

Comment: You still want a unique constraint. If you want to know when a duplicate is attempted, it's easy, just check for a failed insert -- which you should be doing anyway. Then act accordingly -- send the data to a log file, insert into another table, whatever. DO NOT rely on the results of a `SELECT` to determine uniqueness.

Comment: I gave two options in my answer. 1) Make column unique. 2) Use INSERT IGNORE ON DUPLICATE KEY logic, or 3) Use SELECT & then INSERT if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 (DB):  Add a UNIQUE constraint to the table to prevent duplicates.

Step 2 (program):  Do a pre-check against the value and run your code from there.

Pseudocode would look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) LINES FROM MAIN_TABLE WHERE SSN = $attempted_entry
if(LINES <= 0){
    --insert into MAIN_TABLE
} else {
    --insert into POSSIBLE_FRAUD_CHECKS
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a pre-check. Just intercept the failed insert on the main table.

Comment: perhaps, but that assumes the only type of failed insert is on a SSN duplicate.  It sounds from the initial situation that that exact possibility is the ONLY time he wants to redirect the attempt to a possible "fraud" cause.

Comment: No such assumption, the database driver will have a mechanism to check the error type.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is correct here. A `UNIQUE` constraint will prevent duplicates entries in your database.  In order to add the constraint, you will need to make sure there aren't any duplicates existing in your table.  To add the constraint you could use something like the following

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD UNIQUE (SSN)
```

If you want to just set a field based on existing information, I think you can use a case statement in your insert.

```
INSERT INTO table 1 (SSN, DuplicatedSSN) VALUES (999-99-9999, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM orders where SSN = '999-99-9999') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: This tells the OP how to make the column unique, but doesn't actually solve their issue of making sure the SSN doesn't exist before inserting. Of course the insert will fail if it exists already because of the UNIQUE, but it doesn't solve their question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are encrypting SSN information, but here's how you check if there's a duplicate already.. There's a couple ways.

First you should make the database column for SSN have a 'UNIQUE' value. This will prevent there ever being a duplicate.

With your query you should do the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (column1, column2, etc, ssn_column)
VALUES (column1_value, column2_value, etc_value, ssn_value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ssn_column=ssn_column
```

Basically this says...
1) INSERT values into table
2) BUT if the ssn already exists...
3) Update the existing ssn to = ssn (aka do nothing)

This will only insert a new column if it doesn't exist already, but SSN column MUST be a UNIQUE column!

You can also do...

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE ssn = ssn_value
```

if this returns a row... you know it exists...

if nothing exists...

```
INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (values)
```

Comment: Never rely on a SELECT to determine if a subsequent INSERT will work.

Comment: Yeah, that's why my first one is INSERT IGNORE ON DUPLICATE KEY & has the OP make a UNIQUE column first - that way there will never be a duplicate SSN, no matter what.